# Crm Dynamics filter look up

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to filter look up for field manager in entity Position. I need to have only people having the position that I am filling. So new_name  is a field for position name and new_manager_id is a field with look up. Here's my code, that does not work and returns empty list. What can be wrong?

```
    var position_name = Korus.Common.get_attribute_value("new_name");

    position_id = position_id.replace('{', '');
    position_id = position_id.replace('}', '');

    var xml_fetch = "<fetch top=\"50\" >"+
        +"< entity name = \"new_employee\" >"+
        +"<attribute name=\"new_name\" />"+
        +"<filter type=\"and\" >" +
        +"<condition attribute=\"new_position\" operator=\"eq\" value=\"" + position_id + "\" uiname=\"" + position_name + "\" uitype=\"new_position\" />" +
        +"</filter>"+
        +"</entity >"+
        +"</fetch >";

    Korus.Common.addPreSearch("new_managerid", xml_fetch);

addPreSearch(field_name, xml_fetch) {
        if (!this.existance_check(field_name)) {
            var control = Xrm.Page.getControl(field_name);
            control.addPreSearch(this.addCustomFilter(field_name, xml_fetch));
        }
    },
addCustomFilter(field_name, xml_fetch) {
    if (!this.existance_check(field_name)) {
        Xrm.Page.getControl(field_name).addCustomFilter(xml_fetch);
    }
},
```

Comment: How have you configured this code? Running on the `onload` event?

Comment: Yes. I have already solved my problem! I should have passed a function as an argument. In my code I called it when passed